# Simple database app won't retrieve value

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm in the process of learning SQLite and wanted to make my own very simple proof of concept app where I simply store and retrieve a value from a database. I use the NuGet package SQLite-net by Krueger.

My problem is everything seems to work except it doesn't retrieve the value, it crashes at "string a = db.GetAsync(0).Result.storedvalue.ToString();", only saying multiple errors ocurred. Is there something wrong with this line, or perhaps is there something wrong with how I store values in the first place?

[image: Image of app running in emulator]

Here is the complete C# code for the app:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using SQLite;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SimpleDatabaseTest
{
    [Activity(Label = "SimpleDatabaseTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        SQLiteConnection db;
        int i;
        int k;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // create database
            db = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),"test.sqlite"));
            db.CreateTable<somevalues>();

            // set up enter_value and show_value
            EditText enter_value = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.enter_value);
            TextView show_value = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.show_value);

            // store value button
            Button store_value = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.store_value);

            store_value.Click += delegate
            {
                somevalues newTable = new somevalues();
                i = int.Parse(enter_value.Text);

                newTable.storedvalue = i;
                k = newTable.id;
                db.Insert(newTable);

                Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, k.ToString(), ToastLength.Long); //enter_value.Text
                toast.Show();
            };

            // retrieve value button
            Button retrieve_value = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.retrieve_value);

            retrieve_value.Click += delegate
            {
                somevalues some = db.Get<somevalues>("id");
                //string a = some.storedvalue.ToString();

                //Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, a, ToastLength.Long);
                //toast.Show();

                //show_value.Text = a;
            };
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: the db operation is async - so you need to await it's return before you attempt to read the value.  Try unrolling that compound statement into one operation per line instead, it will help you see where the error is

Comment: Agree with @Jason, I think your problem is that you're using asynchronous methods but your trying to use the results of those calls instantly after calling those methods, i.e. synchronously. Calling GetAsync will not return values so that they are immediately available to read, you need to wait for a response; there's probably a callback method you can employ that will trigger on response

Comment: synchronicity was not the issue, I tried both ways and the issue did not resolve

Comment: I get a "Could not open database file" problem now.

Comment: Take a look at this link. I cant say just looking at your code that it does not conform to standard documentation but it differs greatly from any documentation I have seen regarding the creation of tables or querying of them using SQLite. https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlite-net

Comment: "System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements" is the problem I deal with now.

Comment: Which line is that occuring on?

Comment: It's happening at the line "somevalues some = db.Get<somevalues>("id");", where I've also tried using the class-variable "k". Updated code with new code I*m using.